# How to reload an image if getting an error using network image flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a cached network image and sometimes some images throw error of course the package handle this error
but what I want to reload this image again when I press this icon
how can I do That

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to add a `GestureDetector` to your error widget and handle the reload there

```
CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
      placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: ()  {
          // handle your reload and setState/ state management here
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.error) // the placeholder/error image,
      ),
    );
```

EDIT 1 : Using bloc library (cubit as is simple function)

```
var attempts = 0;
return BlocBuilder<YourCubit, YourState>(
        bloc: _yourCubitInstance,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
            placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  //attempts is needed to ensure that retry state is emitted as
                  // bloc library prevents exact same states for being emitted
                  attempts++
                   _yourCubitInstance.refreshImage(attempt: attempts)
                  // above method should emit state to rebuild this widget 
                  // thus retrying the url load
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.error) // the placeholder/error image,
                ),
          );
        });
```

Comment: First thing first Thank U
but I don't have much knowledge of how to reload an image again on the right way so can u help me? i am using bloc but it doesn't matter

Comment: and of course i want a single image reload not all of them

Comment: Generally the errorWidget placeholder exists not for the purpose of reloading, as its almost certain that if the url throws error once, it will continue to do so for a period of time. However for argument sake, I've edited my above answer assuming you were using a Cubit